# Сравнить 3 числа и вывести большее

Tags: html, javascript

Есть три (rezultat, rezultatd, polnsumm) переменные, в которые попадают числа. Как можно сравнить эти переменные и чтобы они в таблице вывелись от большего к меньшему. Проблема ещё в том, что они должны идти строго со своей строчкой таблицы, так как там есть название.

```
container.innerHTML = '<table class="simple-little-table" cellspacing=0><tr><th>Название вклада</th><th>условия вклада</th><th>Прибыль вклада</th></tr><!-- Table Header --><tr><td><a href="#">Вклад срочный </a></td><td>Выплата процентов: ежемесячно</td><td>'+rezultat +' Рублей</td></tr><tr><td><a href="#">Срочный с довлажением</a></td><td>Возможность внесения дополнительных сумм<br>Выплата процентов: ежемесячно</td><td>'+rezultatd+' Рублей</td></tr><!-- Darker Table Row --><tr><td><a href="#">Срочный накопительный</a></td><td>Возможность внесения дополнительных сумм</td><td>'+polnsumm+' Рублей</td></tr><!-- Table Row --></table>'
```

Comment: @eicto первый вариант выводит первое число, второй вариант от меньшего к большему, мне бы их вывести от большего к меньшему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var max=Math.max(rezultat,rezultatd,polnsumm);
```

или надо что-то сложнее ? отсортировать (от меньшего к большему) можно так:

```
var sorted=[rezultat,rezultatd,polnsumm].sort();
```

ещё можно создать массив в каждом элементе которого держать значение, описание и имя. и отсортировать его тем-же sort() с callback. потом вывести всё циклом.